# Parallel protractor tests are still running sequentially

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, jasmine

**Looking For:** I want to run Specs in Parallel.

**Tried:**

Included in config file:

```
shardTestFiles : true,
maxInstances: 4
```

**Output I see:**

Multiple instances are not opening. Still running in serial.

```
**CONFIG.js**
exports.config = {
framework: 'jasmine2',      //framework Used
seleniumPort: 4444,         // selenium port address
specs: ['./Spec/Master.spec.js'],      //inside this i have 50 Specs
allScriptsTimeout: 50000,
jasmineNodeOpts: {                   //jasmine framework details
    isVerbose: true,
    showColors: true,
    includeStackTrace: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 260000,
    print: function() {}
},

capabilities: {
    'browserName':'chrome',
    'chromeOptions':{'args':['--disable-extensions']},
    shardTestFiles : true,
    maxInstances: 4
},
 onPrepare: function (config_) {                  // before starting the actual TC execution, setup the things we define here
    require('./Data/waitReady.js');
    //browser.manage().window().maximize();
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: it's 2020 and I am having same issue. Did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand this sort of parallel test running, I believe "shardTestFiles" will run test files in parallel but if a test file has multiple test cases those will run sequentially on a single browser instance. With your single spec file I would not expect parallel execution when running your config. However, were you to split them up into 4 test files (ex: Master[0-3].spec.js) I would expect to see a test case from each file start at the same time. There's a comment in the config specification that might be helpful to you https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L295 .

Comment: That's exactly why I've asked this question in the comment :)

Comment: Thanks Cherree. will try adding as multiple master specs.

Comment: @cherree ,alecxe . i added 2 specs  in config (//specs: ['Spec/Master_Specs/Master.spec.js','Spec/Master_Specs/FindAcc_MasterSpecs.js'],).             2 instances are opening, but 1st spec runs in both instances, after spec 1 is done. 1 instance is opened to run 2nd spec.       QUESTION : Why duplicate is running in two instances .

Comment: My requirement is , two specs to run in 2 instances and not duplicate running in both instances . Any Helps . Thanks in Advance